# Use bcp to import csv file to sql 2005 or 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, bcp

I have a csv file and i need to import it to a table in sql 2005 or 2008. The column names and count in the csv are different from the table column names and count. The csv is splitted by a ';' .

Example

CSV FILEcontents:

```
FirstName;LastName;Country;Age
Roger;Mouthout;Belgium;55
```

SQL Person Table

```
Columns: FName,LName,Country
```

Comment: What it the world makes this file a CSV (Comma Separated Values) file?

Comment: @EugenioMiró semicolumn as a seperator is something that Excel/Windows uses in countries that have a decimal comma instead of a decimal point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd create a temporary table, bulk insert the lot, select into the new table what you need and drop the temporary table.

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TempImport
(
    FirstName varchar(255),
    LastName varchar(255),
    Country varchar(255),
    Age varchar(255)
)
GO
BULK INSERT dbo.TempImport FROM 'PathToMyTextFile' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.ExistingTable
(
    FName,
    LName,
    Country
)
SELECT  FirstName,
       LastName,
       Country
FROM       dbo.TempImport
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TempImport
GO
```

Comment: The question title was on how to use BCP tool, not bulk insert, although this could be the right answer for most cases, bulk insert presents a few limitations on number of rows and fields that the bcp tool does not.

Comment: Although this is obviously quite some time ago firstly, the question title may mention bcp but the question content simply asks how to import it and secondly there are no row or field limitations in BULK INSERT that don't exist in BCP afaik

Comment: Hi Dan! If you check the official Microsoft documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) it states clearly "When using a format file with BULK INSERT, you can specify up to 1024 fields only. This is same as the maximum number of columns allowed in a table. If you use BULK INSERT with a data file that contains more than 1024 fields, BULK INSERT generates the 4822 error. The bcp utility does not have this limitation, so for data files that contain more than 1024 fields, use the bcp command.". I understand this is a minor issue, but just to keep everyone informed :)

Comment: I have not access to Sql Server, not local, any alternatives ?

Comment: Bulk Insert is a permission even developers may not have in corporate environments. Source: My workplace.

Answer (score 12):

You can use  a format file when importing with bcp:

Create a format file for your table:

```
 bcp [table_name] format nul -f [format_file_name.fmt] -c -T 



 9.0
4
1       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","      1     FName             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","      2     LName             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","      3     Country           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR       0       100     "\r\n"   0     Age               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Edit the import file. The trick is to add a dummy row for the field you want to skip, and add a '0' 
as  server column order.

Then import the data using this format file, specifying your inputfile, this format file and the seperator:

```
bcp [table_name] in [data_file_name] -t , -f [format_file_name.fmt] -T
```

Answer (score 3):

I now prefer to use XML format files like this with BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="|" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="|" MAX_LENGTH="37"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="|" MAX_LENGTH="41"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="|" MAX_LENGTH="17"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="10" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="i" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="j" xsi:type="SQLUNIQUEID"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="k" xsi:type="SQLNUMERIC" PRECISION="18" SCALE="0"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="l" xsi:type="SQLBINARY"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="m" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Then you can use the server-side BULK INSERT command as follows:

```
BULK INSERT foo FROM '\\mydomain.com\bar\bletch' WITH (FORMATFILE='foo.xml', ERRORFILE='foo.errors',  FIRSTROW = 1, BATCHSIZE=10000)
```

alternatively, if you want to modify the data 'in-flight', you can use the

```
INSERT foo(i, j,k)
SELECT foo_delimited.i, foo_delimited.j, foo_delimited.k * 2
 OPENROWSET(BULK 'foo',
                   FORMATFILE= 'foo.xml')
        AS foo_delimited
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the XML to render correctly. One can see the raw XML if you edit the answer :-(

Answer (score 3):

For info, with the same structure, you can use this kind of statement:

```sh
bcp schema.Table in "/Samples/AdventureWorksDW/DimCurrency.csv" \
    -S db.url \
    -d databaseName \ 
    -U userName \
    -P pwd  \
    -t ; # The field separator \
    -c   # Insert as character and doesn't ask the data type  \ 
    -q   # With quote -- seems to be mandatory
```

See [example](https://gerardnico.com/db/sql_server/bcp#csv)