# In SQL Server 2000 how to convert table to text file

Tags: sql-server-2000, ssms, bcp

In SQL Server 2000, I need to convert a table data (whole, not partial) to a text file (csv or tab).

How can I do this with a table (`tblCustomer`) which has name, address, phone number, for example?

I don't use SQL Server Management Studio. I have many groups of stored procedures running on daily basis and just want to write a stored procedure to add in to one of the groups.

Comment: Look at the BCP utility. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954500/export-a-data-table-in-csv-format-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server Management Studio?

If so, just right click on the database name, and choose tasks->export data from the context menu, then follow the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You you are using Management studio, you can try [this](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=353):

> 1. In your SQL Server Management Studio, right-click on the database where the table is and select Tasks->Export Data. This will bring up
>      the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, which is very much similar to
>      the DTS Import/Export utility of SQL Server 2000.
> 2. Select your table from the "Choose a Data Source" screen then click on Next.
> 3. In the "Choose a Destination", select "Flat File Destination" as your Destination and enter the File name.
>
> Just click on Next after that and you should be ok already.

You can also export it to xml using a query and then, on your app, convert it do csv. Check this out: [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)

Or, as @Aaron said, use [The BCP Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

As you said you want the query way, I would go for the `For XML` and them parse the result to a CSV format. AFAIK, SQL server does not have an way of doing what you want automatically, so you will have to make it yourself. Also, you can adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111341/combine-multiple-results-in-a-subquery-into-a-single-comma-separated-value) sample.

[Here](http://www.virtualobjectives.com.au/sqlserver/saving_to_csv.htm) and [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/) you can find some scripts that may help you.

Comment: I don't use SQL Server Management Studio. I have many groups of stored procedures running on daily basis and just want to write a stored procedure to add in to one of the groups.