# How to import data from Excel into SQL Server 2008 

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, excel, stored-procedures

I actually want to import data from an Excel file into an existing database (I use SQL Server 2008 and VB.net) using a T-SQL stored procedure called from my VB.NET app.

So is there a possibility to do that just by coding (without using any other tool SSIS or the SS import and export wizard), if yes can somebody give me just a simple sample of code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to write your stored procedure in VB.NET and use SQL-CLR to run it? Or do you want to write a "regular" T-SQL stored procedure and just call that from VB.NET ?

Comment: Tahnks,actually I want to write in T-SQL and then call it from VB.Net

Comment: SSIS would definitely be the easiest solution - it already has all the code to deal with reading and interpreting Excel ....

Answer (score 0):

You could save your excel file as CSV, and then use bulk insert to import it into Sql Server. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924733/use-bcp-to-import-csv-file-to-sql-2005-or-2008).

Answer (score 0):

Try ADO.NET

[How To Use ADO.NET to Retrieve and Modify Records in an Excel Workbook With Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934)

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to modify data into an excel file , I wanat to import them and store them into a my database!

Comment: So you think because it say retrieve and modify you are required to modify?

Comment: sorry but this article explains how to create an excel workbook and how to update and insert records into it while I don't want this!

Comment: First line in link "This article discusses how you can use ADO.NET to retrieve data from a Microsoft Excel workbook".  RETRIEVE!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Import data to existing database and table, you can use sqlBulkCopy.
See [this sqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

If you need to create table in database sql before copy data, you can use query to create table, example function for create table, you can [see here](http://darrylagostinelli.com/2011/06/27/create-a-sql-table-from-a-datatable-in-c-net/)

And for connection string for file Excel, you can find in [ConnectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Sorry if my english bad..