# How to select a specific column in an excel file worksheet and then store them into an SQL Server database using vb.net

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, excel, excel-2007

hello Actually I just want to store just specific columns into my excisting database(SQL server 2008) I have searched a lot of a way to store them but I really didn't find it, can any body help me please!

Here is my code that I want to implement

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim range As Excel.Range
    Dim rCnt As Integer
    Dim cCnt As Integer
    Dim Obj As Object

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Downloads\B2012.xls")

    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet
    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange



    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import data from Excel into SQL Server 2008 ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404809/how-to-import-data-from-excel-into-sql-server-2008)

Comment: No but the other was with a stored procedure not like this one!I'm trying different ways of solving this problem, and untill now nothing I tried with an OLEDB connection but all I did is to get data from an excel file and store them into my table but there is a condition: colunms in the table stored in the database have to be the same as those in the excel file, while I want specific columns from the excel file!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GetExcelDataforSQLInsert(ByVal fname As String) As Boolean
    Dim prxls As String = fname ' excel file and path
    Dim ok As Boolean = True
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(prxls) Then
            MsgBox(prxls.ToString.Trim + " does not exist.")
            Return False
    End If
    Dim xlApplication As New Application
    Dim xlWrkBook As Workbook
    Dim xlWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim usedRowsCount As Int32
    xlApplication.Visible = False
    xlApplication.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlWrkBook = xlApplication.Workbooks.Open(prxls)
    xlWorksheet = xlWrkBook.Worksheets(1)
    usedRowsCount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count  ' gets count of rows
    Dim i As Int32 = 0, j As Int32 = 0
    Dim RowNum As Integer = 0 ' for looping thru the worksheet
    Dim ColNum As Integer = 1
    Dim prodcat As String = ""  ' these will be the fields inserted in  sqlserver table
    Dim prodcde As String = ""
    Dim prod As String = ""
    Dim pack As String = ""
    Dim cocde As String = ""
    Dim upc As String = ""
    Dim retList As ArrayList = Nothing  ' I return errors and output params from sql with an arraylist
    i = 1
    Do While i <= usedRowsCount
        j = getRowType(xlWorksheet, i) ' I am only importing certain rows so check these in a function
        If j = 1 Then ' J tells me which cell type so I know whether to get it or not
            prodcat = xlWorksheet.Cells(i, C).value.ToString.Trim  ' cell I want
        ElseIf j = 2 Then
            RowNum += 1
            prodcde = xlWorksheet.Cells(i, A).value.ToString.Trim
            prod = xlWorksheet.Cells(i, C).value.ToString.Trim
            pack = xlWorksheet.Cells(i, F).value.ToString.Trim
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(xlWorksheet.Cells(i, D).value) Then
                cocde = ""
            Else
                cocde = xlWorksheet.Cells(i, D).value.ToString.Trim
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(xlWorksheet.Cells(i, E).value) Then
                upc = ""
            Else
                upc = xlWorksheet.Cells(i, E).value.ToString.Trim
            End If
' just call a routine to do an insert query with the cells I have selected
            retList = InsertTempXLrow(RowNum, ConnectionString, prodcat, prodcde, prod, pack, cocde, upc)
            If CInt(retList.Item(0)) <> 0 Then  ' return value
                Dim str As String = ""
                str = "ProdCat: " + prodcat + ControlChars.NewLine
                str += "Prodcde: " + prodcde + ControlChars.NewLine
                str += "Product: " + prod + ControlChars.NewLine
                str += "ProdPack: " + pack + ControlChars.NewLine
                str += ControlChars.NewLine
                str += ControlChars.NewLine + "Your changes were cancelled."

                MessageBox.Show(str, "Database Insert Error" + Convert.ToString(retList.Item(0)))
                ok = False
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        i += 1
    Loop
    xlWrkBook.Close()
    xlApplication.DisplayAlerts = True
    xlApplication.Quit()
    Return ok
End Function
```

Comment: I couldn't get the following in and keep the format (my first foray into formatting) so: add to top of routine: Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel