# CSV file with double quotes in sql sever 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 4GB file and trying to load the data into table using below script. It's raising the below error. Please suggest possible causes.

File size: 4GB
columns in the file: 329

table having 329 columns, every column having varchar(1000).

```
BULK
INSERT npi_db
FROM 'c:\data_20050523-20121008.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

but I am getting:

```
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, 
column 329. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that you are pulling the data into an existing table (is `npi_db` a database or table?). I recommend you first create a valid table with the same formatting as the .csv. This will avoid the problem you are having, which seems to be that the bulk insert does not know what data type the .csv values are being pulled in as. First create the correct table

```
CREATE TABLE CSVTest
(ID INT,
FirstName VARCHAR(40),
LastName VARCHAR(40),
BirthDate SMALLDATETIME);
GO
```

Import to the **table** as follows

```
BULK
INSERT inventory.dbo.fruits
FROM 'C:\fruit\inventory.txt' 
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
GO
```

You could also look at loading the file using SQL Server's [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646(v=sql.80).aspx). With this utility you can specify the format of the data being bulled in using a [format file (.fmt)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx).

See [Use bcp to import csv file to sql 2005 or 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924733/use-bcp-to-import-csv-file-to-sql-2005-or-2008) for more information on what you want...

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i am trying as like below is this work?C:\>bcp inventory.dbo.fruits in "C:\fruit\inventory.txt" -c -T

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the above comment... Okay I see the edit. Check out the BCP documentation and if neccessary ask another question. BCP is fast - so may be a good option. However, if invintory and fruits are you DB and table, then your `BULK INSERT` above is not correct.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion..i tried using this one it's raising the error..Starting copy...  bcp npi_db in "E:\Platform Q\npidata_20050523-20121008_test1.csv"
SQLState = S1001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Memory allocation failure

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 145034

Comment: See my edit to the answer above. Try BULK INSERT first - using the edited code above. If you decide to switch to using BCP instead - again see edit...

Comment: i tried with bulk insert it's not working..it's raisng the same error..what i have to do "The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 329. 
Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly."

Comment: Well, the error is telling you the problem. Check the csv for valid row terminators and commas. It seems like there are formatting issues in the CSV now...