# Using BCP to copy a CSV file from Linux box to a remote MS SQL server?

Tags: python, sql, linux, centos, bcp

I have a very large Pandas DataFrame (100s of millions of rows).

I want to use `bcp` to copy a CSV file saved from Pandas to a remote MS SQL server. This should be quicker than using Pandas `to_csv`.

However, I'm unsure how to use `bcp` to write a local CSV file to a remote MS SQL server.

Suggestions?

Comment: do you have to write the csv file to a table on the remote SQL server db?

Comment: @vkp Yes, the contents of the CSV file needs to be written to a table on the remote SQL server. I have been using pands `to_sql` to do this originally, but it is way too slow for the size dataframes I have now.

Comment: [`this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924733/use-bcp-to-import-csv-file-to-sql-2005-or-2008) may help

Comment: @vkp Thanks - it seems that answer is geared towards using the bcp tool locally. I need to figure out how to specify server, username, login, etc. in the bcp tool itself.

Comment: [`bcp command`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) has all those options which can be specified.

Comment: @vkp I'm tryign to use this from the linux command line and it's a bit of a nightmare. If I do `bcp mytable in mycsv.csv -s serverip -U username -d database -t delimiter`, I get the error 'unknown argument -s'.

Comment: `-S`,  `s`should be upper-case

Comment: @vkp now I get `unknown argument -U`

Comment: did you use the corresponding username to login to the database?