# Convert Microsoft Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, bcp

I need to convert a Microsoft Access database (`*.accdb`) to SQL Server by command line in Linux.

Every time I run this task it should do:

1. Empty the database
2. Import the whole data from Microsoft Access database to SQL Server

My first idea was use `mdb-tools` to create a `script.sql` like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

MDB="$1"
DIALECT="sybase"

cat << EOF
-- Something to DROP all tables (not tested yet)
DECLARE @DropConstraints NVARCHAR(max) = ''
SELECT @DropConstraints += 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) + ' ' + 'DROP CONSTRAINT' + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM sys.foreign_keys
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DropConstraints;
GO

DECLARE @DropTables NVARCHAR(max) = ''
SELECT @DropTables += 'DROP ' + REPLACE(TABLE_TYPE, 'BASE ', '') + ' ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE in ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW')
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DropTables;
GO
EOF > script.sql

mdb-schema "$MDB" "$DIALECT" >> script.sql

TABLES=$(mdb-tables -1 "$MDB")
for table in $TABLES; do
    mdb-export -D '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -I "$DIALECT" "$MDB" $table >> script.sql
done
```

and then run `script.sql` in my SQL Server database with `mssql-cli -S ***** -U ***** -U ***** -P ***** -d ***** -i script.sql`

But it is to slow and I need something more direct.

I think I could do with [`bcp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) but I don't find any example.

Comment: An upsert would likely be better than a truncate everything, `INSERT` everything. Why do you have to use command line? Why can't you use an ETL tool?

Comment: `mdb-export -I` will generate an individual INSERT statement for each row in the table. If you export a CSV file then you should be able to use `bcp` to import the data into the tables that you create via the CREATE TABLE statements generated by `mdb-schema`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/924733/2144390) might help you with the `bcp` part.